# Invalid call require(source) when creating Image component with ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my `ImageView.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

interface Props {
  width?: number;
  name: string;
}

export const ImageView = (props: Props) => {
  const source = '../../assets/' + props.name;
  return <Image width={props.width} source={require(source)} />;
};
```

and this is how I call it from other component:

```
<ImageView name={'images/splash.png'} />
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

What is wrong with that line?

My files hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: This topic is covered at: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources -> _"In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically."_

Comment: Ok, I understand your helpful topic, but do I have always write a full path of the image to make it working? Cant I just pass the name with props? It is weird for me...

Comment: Imagine it like this: writing `require('something')` will tell RN that the 'something' is somewhere in your project and must be bundled into the final product. If this 'something' is dynamic, RN cannot know what is it and where it is. Welcome to RN Dev world :)

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear I shall provide an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/static-images):

```js
import { View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

const localAssets = {
  elon: require('./assets/elon.jpeg'),
  bill: require('./assets/bill.jpeg'),
  mark: require('./assets/mark.jpeg'),
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={localAssets.mark} />
        <Image style={styles.image} source={localAssets.elon} />
        <Image style={styles.image} source={localAssets.bill} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  imageContainer: { backgroundColor: '#ff00ff', flex: 1 },
  image: {
    borderColor: '#00ff00',
    borderWidth: 3,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
});
```

Static images you want to use must be explicit imported with `require` as done and assigned to `localAssets`.

When the bundler recognizes the `require` with an static uri the bundler will ship the app with the images.

That's why it's not possible to use a dynamic `require` like `require('./assets/'+image)`, this way the bundler won't be able to determine which images should be shipped with the app.